# Como chamar uma função por um parametro usando argparse?

Tags: python, argumento

Consegui chamar funções apenas criando subparsers mas sobraram dois parâmetros que fazem parte do parser, tem alguma forma correta de passar uma função na declaração do argumento? Exemplo:

```
parser.add_argument("-l", "--list", chamar_funcao=nome_da_funcao, help=...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tudo o que o ArgParser faz é ler os parâmetros da linha de comando, de acordo com
a especificação que você monta ao chamar os `.add_argument` e devolver um objeto que tem os valores das opções passadas, quando você chama `.parse_args`.

Se quiser chamar funções específicas, você tem que colocar isso no seu programa, usando estruturas como `if getattr(args, ...):` (ou outras):

Exemplo de argparse:

```py
import argparse

def list(param):
    print(f"listagem de coisas: {param}")


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Exemplo')
    parser.add_argument('--list', "-l", type=str,
                        help='Lista os objetos do tipo citado')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if getattr(args, "list", None):
        list(args.list)
    else:
        print("Nenhuma opção passada")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

A documentação do `argparse` é bem doida - por que ela, desde o primeiro exemplo, coloca objetos to tipo função (sum e max) como parâmetros
de "default" e "const" do exemplo, e depois, ao falar dos sub_parsers, também coloca uma função como "default" - mas o objeto Parser não
chama essas funções diretamente: o que chama a função é fazer algo do tipo

```
# isso cria um "paramtro escondido" "func" no subparser,
# com o valor sendo a função "foo":
parser_foo.set_defaults(func=foo)

...
# isso pega o objeto Python guardado no parâmetro "escondido"
# e usa esse parâmetro como uma função:

args.func(args)
```

Eu acho esse approach meio esotérico demais, e um pouco gambiarrístico:
se for usar o parseargs, prefira usar "if"s puros e simples: fica fácil
entender o que você está fazendo.

Se preferir mesmo agilizar a chamada de várias funções, melhor usar uma lib de argumentos mais limpa que o ArgParse, como a [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/): ela sim, deixa marcar funções com decoradores, que podem depois ser chamadas automaticamente com opções da linha de comando.

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou bastante, mas realmente muito doida a documentação, vou acabar usando Click kkk